# Why are most (all?) Obfuscation-tools directed to C# and other C-languages and not VB?

Tags: obfuscation

I dont know if I'm right, but allmost everytime I read about obfuscation and tools that handle it, then its about C#, Java, Javascript and all other languages than VB.

As I can see its equal important for me as a VB-developer to *protect* my code as an C#-developer. Have I missed something?

Please dont flame me if it somehow is obvious why but I haved missed it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you mean VB.NET, it can be obfuscated the same way as C#, since the obfuscators work with the assemblies, and not the source code. Since C# and VB.NET compiles into (almost) the same IL, it will work with both of them.

Comment: It tought it would be like that. 
Maybe I'm sitting with old information from pre-.Net and that makes me confused.

Comment: VB 6 and earlier can´t use the same obfuscators as C# since they are not built the same way at all. 

If you are satisfied with the answer, please mark as solved.

Comment: I will follow the QA and wait a couple of hours before I accept. But in meantime its a +1

Answer (score 8):

VB.NET's default is Obfuscation = true.

It's a joke. Relax. I couldn't help myself. vimpyboy nailed it.